# how do I make a slideshow that has an animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to make a category and I want to make it as a slider so I want once the user click on any category it goes to the left and become bigger,
here is a link how the slide works : [slideshow](https://dribbble.com/shots/14108605-Star-Game-Dashboard)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to add onClick event to all Categories

you already has array of categories

if not, you need to store all categories in array

and when user click on category you want to make [circular shift] for array
and then re-render it.

circular shift
[image]